# References in PDF Bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks, arxiv

I want to refer to a lemma in a section heading. I do that like this:

```
\section{Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:main}}
```

The problem is that when I submit my paper to arXiv the PDF bookmark for this section becomes "Proof of Lemma ??" (everything else looks fine). I don't have this problem when I compile the paper on my computer. I think that this problem happens because arXiv runs PDFLaTeX only twice; but one has to run it three times to get correct PDF bookmarks. Is there a work around for this problem?

(I use hyperref and compile the TeX file with PDFLaTex.)

Comment: Can you submit only the PDF file there?

Comment: In the final version of the document that you submit you could just use  `\section{Proof of Lemma~3.5}` (or whatever number you need) (low tech but easier than getting arxiv to reconfigure:-)

Comment: @Sigur: Unfortunately, no, they don't accept PDF files generated by LaTeX; I have to submit a LaTeX file. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I will do that if there is no simple workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please load package `bookmark`. It is able to need only one compile run to get ready-to-use bookmarks.  More information you get with `texdoc bookmark`.